# Qt, how to collapse column in QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, collapsable

When I hold the right border of column in QTableView and try to change it`s size, all works fine except one thing: there is a minimal size of column, something about 20 pixels. But I need a possibility to collapse this column to zero size, if I wish so.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can try method `setMinimumSectionSize(int size)` of `QHeaderView` (Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#minimumSectionSize-prop).

For example:

```
YourTableView->horizontalHeader()->setMinimumSectionSize(0);
```